# yii-bootstrap tbmenu title

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, menu, yii

How can i add 'title' attribute to an item?

like this?

```
<?php
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbMenu', array(
    'type' => 'tabs', // '', 'tabs', 'pills' (or 'list')
    'stacked' => false, // whether this is a stacked menu
    'items' => array(...
array(
            'label' => 'member',
            'url'=>'#',
            'htmlOptions'=>array('title' => 'manage member'),
            'items' => array(...
```

or like this?

```
 array(
            'label' => 'member',
            'url'=>array('#','htmlOptions'=>array('title' => 'manage member'),
```

but both ways can not output target like
<a href="" titel="manage member">member</a>
then ,how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `linkOptions => array('title' => 'Your title')` instead of `htmlOptions`